# Is there an opposite of the "wildcard" operator to specifically not find specified items in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I found it difficult to pose a title for this question so I will try and explain my problem as best I can here.

In Prolog, you can use the _ operator in a predicate to obtain all the definitions regardless of what exists there, in my example:

```
%footballer is in the form: footballer(lastname,team,goals_scored)

%footballer(N,T,G).
footballer(rooney,manchesterutd,15).
footballer(ronaldo,madrid,20).
footballer(bale,madrid,17).
footballer(messi,barca,25).
```

and here, if I wanted to find all the players that play for madrid, I could use:

```
footballer(X,madrid,_).
```

and it would return the players of interest, regardless of goals scored.

What I actually want however, is given the predefined team madrid, all the players that are not members of madrid. Something like:

```
footballer(X,not(madrid),_).
```

Does such a thing exist? I'm using Prolog version 5.10.2.

Thanks

Comment: `?- footballer(X,C,_),C \= madrid.`

Answer (score 4):

You want syntactic inequality:

```
?- dif(T, madrid), footballer(X, T, _).
```

Comment: typo: should be `dif(T, madrid)`